# Get difference between two dates using ms access for each and store in the same table

Tags: sql, date, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I got a table with the following columns in MSaccess:

- Terminated
- Last login
- Days After Termination

The [Days After Termination] is the difference between [Last login] field and the [Terminated] field.

SO I want my query to calculate the difference between [Last Login] field and the [Terminated] and store it in the [Days After Termination], I want to do it for each record in the table. the dates are stored in 2015.03.12 format.

I have tried the following:

```
SELECT  a.[user],SUM(a.[Last Login]- a.[Terminated]) AS [Days After]
FROM Finding as a 
inner join 
(Select   [user],SUM(Finding.[Last Login]- Finding.[Terminated] AS [Days After]
from Finding
) AS b
ON b.[user]=a.[user]
;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Storing results that can be obtained from a query breaks normalization. Access 2010 allows calculated columns, but just because you can, does not mean you should. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-calculated-field-to-a-table-14a60733-2580-48c2-b402-6de54fafbde3

Answer (score 0):

I **assume** that each row in your table is an employee; if that is not the case, you will have to provide more information in order to more fully respond to your question.

Under that assumption, there is no reason to calculate the "Days After Termination" field.  Whenever you need that value, simply create a calculated field in the query that retrieves the data you want.  For example:

```
SELECT <Employee Name>, [Last Login]-Terminated AS Delay FROM <Employee Table>
```

Does that help?